# How to detect a UIGesture is added on a view.(objective c)

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have to check if any gesture is attached to a view or not. Actually my need is to restrict touch down action of a button, if any gesture recognizer is attached on it. (I am using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every UIView object has a property called `gestureRecognizers` which is the array of all the gesture recognizers attached to that view and returns an empty array if no gesture recognizers are attached.

Refer [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/gestureRecognizers) for the apple reference.

So:

```
if (yourView.gestureRecognizers.count ==0 ){
   //let the touch down action work
}else{
   //restrict the touch down action
}
```